Dataset MaxItems not working for deeply nested dataset
I have a 6 layer deep Dataset.
When I try to do
Dataset[...,MaxItems->Table[All,6]]

The rows in the second layer are not showing:

What other parameters are available?

I'm not sure I know what a 6 layer deep dataset is. Can you just provide a minimal dataset so we don't have to try to come up with our own data speculatively?
